# Adding dates to each element in a list

Tags: r

I have this list with 20 data frames in them. I want to add the dates to them so that each data frame has its own date. For example

```
mylist[1] %>% 
    mutate (date = 2020-09-01)
```

then

```
mylist[2] %>% 
    mutate (date = 2020-09-02)
```

Something like this in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here a loop approach. I have created a dummy list of dataframes using `iris` dataset. In order to assign the data you must also have an object with the date values. I created a dummy date vector named `vdate`. Next the code:

```
#Data
List <- list(df1=iris,df2=iris,df3=iris)
#Dates
vdate <- seq(Sys.Date(),by=1,length.out = 3)
#Loop
for(i in 1:length(vdate))
{
  #Assign new variable
  List[[i]]$date <- vdate[i]
}
#Some rows
head(List[[1]])
head(List[[2]])
head(List[[3]])
```

Output:

```
head(List[[1]])

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species       date
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa 2020-09-07
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa 2020-09-07
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa 2020-09-07
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa 2020-09-07
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa 2020-09-07
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa 2020-09-07

head(List[[2]])

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species       date
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa 2020-09-08
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa 2020-09-08
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa 2020-09-08
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa 2020-09-08
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa 2020-09-08
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa 2020-09-08

head(List[[3]])

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species       date
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa 2020-09-09
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa 2020-09-09
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa 2020-09-09
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa 2020-09-09
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa 2020-09-09
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa 2020-09-09
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
dates <- your list_of_dates

library(dplyr)
sapply(1:length(mylist), function(x){
  mylist[[x]]%>% mutate(date = dates[[x]])
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the replacement function `` `[<-` `` within a `Map`call.

```
Map(`[<-`, LIST, "date", value=dates)
# [[1]]
#   X1 X2 X3 X4       date
# 1  1  4  7 10 2020-09-07
# 2  2  5  8 11 2020-09-07
# 3  3  6  9 12 2020-09-07
# 
# [[2]]
#   X1 X2 X3 X4       date
# 1  1  4  7 10 2020-09-08
# 2  2  5  8 11 2020-09-08
# 3  3  6  9 12 2020-09-08
# 
# [[3]]
#   X1 X2 X3 X4       date
# 1  1  4  7 10 2020-09-09
# 2  2  5  8 11 2020-09-09
# 3  3  6  9 12 2020-09-09
```

---

*Example data:*

```
LIST <- replicate(3, data.frame(matrix(1:12, 3, 4)), simplify=F)
dates <- seq(as.Date("2020-09-07"), by="day", length.out=3)
```